# How to scale a TikZ image which is within a figure environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-trees

I have the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
  dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}

\begin{document}

this is the thing

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    root/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=green, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    main/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=pink, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    fact/.style={rectangle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,
    % 
    % this line will scale the tikz image but messes up the text
    % transform canvas={scale=0.6}
]
\node (State00) [main] {Question} [->]
        child{ [sibling distance=9cm]
            node (State01) [state] {One}
            child{
                node (Fact02) [fact] {yes}
                child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                    node (State02) [leaf] {Good}
                }
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                node (Fact10) [fact] {no}
                child{
                    node (State10) [state] {Two}
                    child{
                        node (Fact11) [fact] {yes}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Good}
                        }
                    }
                    child{
                        node (Fact12) [fact] {no}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Bad}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    % }   
;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Decision Tree]{%
        %
        \emph{Basic decision tree 
        %
        }}
    \label{tikz:decision-tree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which will out put :

[image]

Un-commenting the line

```
    % transform canvas={scale=0.6}
```

will scale the Ti*k*Z image, but as a result the formatting is broken.

[image]

I would like to be able to scale the Ti*k*Z image, but keep the formatting otherwise intact.

Comment: Add `scale=0.6` only?

Comment: @JouleV thanks, that seems to mainly shrink the width, whereas i was interested in shrinking the overall tree

Comment: `transform canvas` is necessary to scale down the nodes, as, normally, we do not want to mess up with the font sizes and line widths. The problem is that `transform canvas` makes the tikz forget about the original drawing bounding box, thus it scales everything but "missplaces" it...

Comment: A hack would be to add a `\rule{0pt}{5.5cm}` inside the argument of your caption

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uhm, what's wrong with `scale=0.6`? It does shrink the overall tree without the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
  dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    root/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=green, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    main/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=pink, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    fact/.style={rectangle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,
    % 
    % this line will scale the tikz image but messes up the text
    % transform canvas={scale=0.6}
    scale=0.6
]
\node (State00) [main] {Question} [->]
        child{ [sibling distance=9cm]
            node (State01) [state] {One}
            child{
                node (Fact02) [fact] {yes}
                child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                    node (State02) [leaf] {Good}
                }
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                node (Fact10) [fact] {no}
                child{
                    node (State10) [state] {Two}
                    child{
                        node (Fact11) [fact] {yes}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Good}
                        }
                    }
                    child{
                        node (Fact12) [fact] {no}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Bad}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    % }   
;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Decision Tree]{%
        %
        \emph{Basic decision tree 
        %
        }}
    \label{tikz:decision-tree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to make the whole thing (including font size) smaller, `\scalebox` may be a good option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
  dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.6}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    root/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=green, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    main/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=pink, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    fact/.style={rectangle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,
    % 
    % this line will scale the tikz image but messes up the text
    % transform canvas={scale=0.6}
]
\node (State00) [main] {Question} [->]
        child{ [sibling distance=9cm]
            node (State01) [state] {One}
            child{
                node (Fact02) [fact] {yes}
                child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                    node (State02) [leaf] {Good}
                }
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                node (Fact10) [fact] {no}
                child{
                    node (State10) [state] {Two}
                    child{
                        node (Fact11) [fact] {yes}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Good}
                        }
                    }
                    child{
                        node (Fact12) [fact] {no}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Bad}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    % }   
;
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption[Decision Tree]{%
        %
        \emph{Basic decision tree 
        %
        }}
    \label{tikz:decision-tree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Well, `\scalebox` also has its drawback. Therefore I think resetting the font size of all nodes, as [Guilherme Zanotelli](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/81905/guilherme-zanotelli) suggested, is nicer, but you have to do it manually. Here I use `\footnotesize`.

[image]

---

If you don't like doing things manually, let Ti*k*Z help by `transform shape`, proposed by [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) in the comments (thank you very much). This option will change the font size in the scale given. However, sometimes you will get a supertiny font size, which is hard to read.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
  dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    root/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=green, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    main/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=pink, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black},
    fact/.style={rectangle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,
    % 
    % this line will scale the tikz image but messes up the text
    % transform canvas={scale=0.6}
    scale=0.6,transform shape
]
\node (State00) [main] {Question} [->]
        child{ [sibling distance=9cm]
            node (State01) [state] {One}
            child{
                node (Fact02) [fact] {yes}
                child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                    node (State02) [leaf] {Good}
                }
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=4cm]
                node (Fact10) [fact] {no}
                child{
                    node (State10) [state] {Two}
                    child{
                        node (Fact11) [fact] {yes}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Good}
                        }
                    }
                    child{
                        node (Fact12) [fact] {no}
                        child{
                            node (State11) [leaf] {Bad}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    % }   
;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Decision Tree]{%
        %
        \emph{Basic decision tree 
        %
        }}
    \label{tikz:decision-tree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many ways to do it. Choose the one you like best ;)

Comment: Using `scale=0.6` plus `every node/.style={font=\desiredfontsize}` properly scales the picture while maintaining font properties. =D

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Seeing the OP's second image, I don't think (s)he wants to keep the font size.

Comment: keeping font size is a nice option - do i just add `every node/.style={font=\desiredfontsize}` into the tikz options? Thank you Joule

Comment: @baxx Well, you have at least three options to choose from right now. Choose whatever you want :)

Comment: If you use `scale=0.6,transform shape` the fonts will be transformed, too. (`\scalebox` may cause trouble if you want to work with `remember pictrue`.)

Comment: @marmot You can always write an answer, and I can always upvote your answer :) Your proposal is very nice!

Comment: @JouleV No need. Your answer is great and I do not like "picking". But you could just add this alternative. (And of course I gave +1.)

Comment: @JouleV My sincere compliments (+1) also for me. :-) I saw your profile :-): I can ask you a question, I apologize before.

Comment: @Sebastiano What do you apologize for? I don't really understand.

Comment: @marmot Well, I will add your option as requested.

Comment: @JouleV My only curiosity was that you're very good at math. Since it's something personal, I generally don't ask for something private in my life.

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Since when `\desiredfontsize` is defined? I am using a (not up-to-date) compiler and it tells me that the command is not defined.

Comment: @JouleV it's not, hahahaha. It's meant as "desired font size command" \footnotesize and etcetera! ;D

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Ohh, you made my day :) I am completely trolled :D